# Why do some joins not work without selectKey first?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In doing my joins, I am finding that the 2nd block tends to give the expected result, whereas the 1st block does not and never hits the `(aValue, bValue) -> myFunc(aValue, bValue)`. I didn't think the actual key mattered as long as I set the right field to join on `(aKey, aValue) -> aValue.get("someField").asText()`, but there is something about using `.selectKey((aKey, aValue) -> aValue.get("someField").asText())` beforehand that makes the join go through correctly. I have also seen some cases that did not require the `selectKey`. Can someone explain the difference?

```
// does not join correctly and gives unexpected result
KStream<String, JsonNode> c = a
  .leftJoin(b,
    (aKey, aValue) -> aValue.get("someField").asText(),
    (aValue, bValue) -> myFunc(aValue, bValue)
);
```

```
// does join correctly and gives expected result
KStream<String, JsonNode> c = a
  .selectKey((aKey, aValue) -> aValue.get("someField").asText())
  .leftJoin(b,
    (aKey, aValue) -> aKey,
    (aValue, bValue) -> myFunc(aValue, bValue)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different joins with different semantics in Kafka Streams and I am not 100% sure what join you execute?

Given your example, it seems you are using a `KStream-GlobalKTable` join; `b` seems to be a `GlobalKTable` and the second argument (i.e., `(aKey, aValue) -> aValue.get("someField").asText()` is your `keySelector`?

If this it correct, the first code snippet looks correct to me. What version are you using (maybe there is some bug in Kafka Streams)? Can you also share the output of `Topology#describe()#toString()` for both cases?